# Python docx add_paragraph() inserts leading newline

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

I'm able to use a paragraph object to select font size, color, bold, etc. within a table cell. But, `add_paragraph()` seems to always insert a leading \n into the cell and this messes up the formatting on some tables.

If I just use the `cell.text('')` method it doesn't insert this newline but then I can't control the text attributes.

Is there a way to eliminate this leading newline?

Here is my function:

```
def add_table_cell(table, row, col, text, fontSize=8, r=0, g=0, b=0, width=-1):
    cell = table.cell(row,col)
    if (width!=-1):
    cell.width = Inches(width)
    para = cell.add_paragraph(style=None)
    para.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.LEFT
    run = para.add_run(text)
    run.bold = False
    run.font.size = Pt(fontSize)
    run.font.color.type == MSO_COLOR_TYPE.RGB
    run.font.color.rgb = RGBColor(r, g, b)
```

Answer (score 7):

I tried the following and it worked out for me. Not sure if is the best approach:

`cells[0].text = 'Some text'   #Write the text to the cell`

`#Modify the paragraph alignment, first paragraph`
`cells[0].paragraphs[0].paragraph_format.alignment=WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.CENTER`

Answer (score 3):

The solution that I find is to use *text* attribute instead of add_paragraph() but than use add_run():

```
row_cells[0].text = ''
row_cells[0].paragraphs[0].add_run('Total').bold = True
row_cells[0].paragraphs[0].paragraph_format.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.RIGHT
```

Comment: If I want to change the color?

Answer (score 2):

I've look through the documentation of cell, and it's not the problem of add_paragraph(). The problem is when you having a cell, by default, it will have a paragraph inside it.

> class docx.table._Cell:
>
> > paragraphs: ... By default, a new cell contains a single paragraph. Read-only

Therefore, if you want to add paragraphs in the first row of cell, you should first delete the default paragraph first. Since python-docx don't have paragraph.delete(), you can use the function mention in this github issue: [feature: Paragraph.delete()](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/33#issuecomment-77661907)

```py
def delete_paragraph(paragraph):
    p = paragraph._element
    p.getparent().remove(p)
    p._p = p._element = None
```

Therefore, you should do something like:

```
cell = table.cell(0,0)
paragraph = cell.paragraphs[0]
delete_paragraph(paragraph)
paragraph = cell.add_paragraph('text you want to add', style='style you want')
```

---

Update at 10/8/2022 
Sorry, the above approach is kinda unnecessary.
It's much intuitive to edit the default paragraph instead of first deleting it and add it back.
For the function `add_table_cell`, just replace the `para = cell.paragraphs[0]`
and `para.style = None`, the `para.style = None` is not necessary as it should be default value for a new paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me. I don't call add_paragraph(). I just reference the first paragraph with this call -> para = cell.paragraphs[0].  Everything else after that is the usual api calls.

```
table = doc.add_table( rows=1, cols=3 )   #   bar codes

for tableRow in table.rows:
    for cell in tableRow.cells:
        para = cell.paragraphs[0]
        run = para.add_run( "*" + specIDStr + "*" )
        font = run.font
        font.name = 'Free 3 of 9'
        font.size = Pt( 20 )

        run = para.add_run( "\n" + specIDStr 
            + "\n" + firstName + " " + lastName
            + "\tDOB: " + dob )
        font = run.font
        font.name = 'Arial'
        font.size = Pt( 8 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example solution starting from creating the text_frame:

```
cell_tf = cell_box.text_frame
cell_paragraph = cell_tf.paragraphs[0] # instead of cell_tf.add_paragraph()
```

`add_paragraph()` inserts a new paragraph (newline character). But unintuitively, new `text_frame` objects come pre-built with a paragraph in them (`paragraph[0]`). When we call `add_paragraph()`, we are adding an additional paragraph to the one that is already (secretly) there, creating this leading newline problem.